# filter an array of object with same id

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let's say i have a json like this:

```
[
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'A',
        depth:0
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'C'
        depth:1
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'B',
        depth:1
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Z'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'F',
        depth:0
    }
]
```

what i want to do is to create another array of object with these rules:

1: find the same ids in array

2: check the depth (so if depth was 0 it should be the parent and if depth was 1 it should be the child of element with depth 0)

like this :

```
[
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'A',
        depth:0,
        child:[
            {
                id: 3,
                name: 'B',
                depth:1
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Z'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'F',
        depth:0,
        child:[
            {
                id: 2,
                name: 'C',
                depth:1,

            },
        ]
    }
]
```

Any help would be appreciated it ?

Comment: I think you can use forEach... what happens if there is a depth: 2? what have you done so far?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go..

```js
    var a = [
        {
            id: 3,
            name: 'A',
            depth:0
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: 'C',
            depth:1
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            name: 'B',
            depth:1
        },
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Z'
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: 'F',
            depth:0
        }]
        var c = a.filter(a => a.depth == 0);
        var zeroDepth = a.filter(a => a.depth === undefined);
        zeroDepth.forEach(z => c.push(z));
        a.forEach(a => 
          {
            if(a.depth == 1){
            c.forEach(c => 
            {
              if(c.id == a.id){
                c.child = [];
                c.child.push(a);
           }
          })
         }
        })
    console.log(c);
```